# Two DIVs aligning side by side at the same start level

Tags: html, css, layout

I have (like on the picture) put two boxes next to eachother.
I have done that two times.

My problem is that it shouldn't matter if one of the boxes is longer than the other.
They should start at the same level.
It's easier if you look at the pictures.
Right now the boxes is placed wrong.
What can I do?
Thank you in advance!

Here are the two pictures:

What I have right now: (the red line shows where the boxes should start)
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Comment: You need to provide your code, what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box short"></div>
    <div class="box long"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box long"></div>
    <div class="box short"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. CSS:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 10px
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100px;
}

.long {
  height: 200px
}

.short {
  height: 100px
}
```

3. Codepen:
   https://codepen.io/takhirkudusov/pen/jOXGwez